# Python sqlalchemy type varchar is inserting alphanumeric through dataframe to_sql instead of text

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert data into oracle database through pandas to_sql

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

oracle_connection_string = ('oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@'+
                           cx_Oracle.makedsn('{hostname}', 
                 '{port}', service_name='{service_name}'))

engine = create_engine(oracle_connection_string.format(
                        username='test',
                        password ='test',
                        hostname='test.server.com',
                        port='1521',
                        service_name='test.server.net'
                        )) ### Default encoding is utf-8 as i am using python3

df = pd.DataFrame(["Create Buying Opportunity as Underlying ",
"strategic optimisation to drive more",
"Deliver Growth Without Sacrificing Margins",
"while expanding operating margins"], columns=["column1"])

df.column1 = df.column1.str.encode('utf8')
###This is required because I have some non ascii characters in my text

####Below is the output of the dataframe - df
column1
0   b'Create Buying Opportunity as Underlying '
1   b'strategic optimisation to drive more'
2   b'Deliver Growth Without Sacrificing Margins'
3   b'while expanding operating margins'
```

If I directly push the data to oracle DB it is working without any issue but the only challenge is, it is taking forever to insert 145K records using below code

```py
df.to_sql(name='TEST_TABLE', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

As the above command is taking more time, as per the suggestions by other users from github i have made changes as below

```py
dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max())
    for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}


df.to_sql(name='TEST_TABLE', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=dtyp)
```

Now the data is inserted into the table as '415041432053656D69636F6E647563746F7' instead of text 'Create Buying Opportunity as Underlying'

Comment: b'This is oracle' is actual data present in the dataframe but the data is inserted in the oracle database is '4AB78910CMKLN09' (example values) not the acutal text 'This is oracle'. Seems like  'b' present before the text is causing the issue when converting it to VARCHAR if i trim out 'b' using decode UTF-8 i am getting unicode errors while inserting into database

Comment: Thanks for your reply Parfait. I am unable to post the exact data because of data sensitivity issue. The problem is I  have text with non ascii characters, when I am directly pushing the data to db i am getting  UnicodeEncodeError so I have encoded that text as 'utf-8' using str.encode('utf8') in pandas dataframe. So the text came as prefixed with 'b'(eg: b'This is oracle'). When i am trying to push this data after changing it as VARCHAR in dtype it is inserting raw text in oracle database

Comment: The reason for changing it to VARCHAR as direct to_sql object data type is taking forever to insert into the DB. Seems like the issue is with to_sql handling dtypes when utf-8 text with prefix 'b' is present

Comment: Thank you very much @Parfait I have made the changes to the question as per the suggestions. I am using sqlalchemy in python3

Comment: Regarding overall performance, does Pandas's `to_sql` use cx_Oracle's `executemany()` ? https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle  I tried a test with cx_Oracle natively inserting 145K records to a DB on the same machine as Python.  Each record was  a number and a short string.  Using `execute()` took 85 seconds to insert.  Using `executemany()` took 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Update: I logged https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4750  If anyone uses the patch in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8953, then try with `executemany()`

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for your suggestion on connect_args, i have added those arguments and pushed it to db still the raw characters were pushed instead of actual text. Regarding decode i am not doing it anymore. I am encoding it as utf-8 as it has non ascii and trying to push it to db through to_sql

Comment: @ChristopherJones thanks for your inputs , to_sql is working fast as long as the python dataframe is not having any object data type which is having text of average 200 charcters. Challenge is pushing the utf-8 encoded data to db which is having object data type with average 200 characters length